# Filter multiindex df based on std

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

```
df.groupby(['name','cat'])['valtocount'].agg('count')
```

through the above I get the following multindex df:

```
name cat count
abc  a   1
     b   1
def  a   1
     c   2
```

I want to keep only the names where the std of count is >0
do you guys have any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with `std` or [`SeriesGroupBy.nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.nunique.html) and filtering by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
s = df.groupby(['name','cat'])['valtocount'].agg('count')
s1 = s[s.groupby(level=0).transform('std') > 0]
print (s1)
name  cat
def   a      1
      c      2
Name: valtocount, dtype: int64
```

---

```
s1 = s[s.groupby(level=0).transform('nunique') != 1]
```